# Getting The Wait Operation Timeout Exception for a query from Skip Value 100

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am writing a small data migration tools from one big database to another small database. All of the others data migration method worked satisfactorily, but the following method has given an exception from the **SKIP VALUE IS 100**. I run this console script remotely as well as inside of the source server also. I tried in many different was to find the actual problem what it is. After then I found that only from the **SKIP VALUE IS 100** it is not working for any **TAKE 1,2,3,4,5 or ...**.

Dear expertise, I don't have any prior knowledge on that type of problem. Any kind of suggestions or comments is appreciatable to resolve this problem. Thanks for you time.

I know this code is not clean and the method is too long. I just tried solve this by adding some line of extra code. Because the problem solving is my main concern. I just copy past the last edited method.

In shot the problem I can illustrate with this following two line

```
var temp = queryable.Skip(90).Take(10).ToList(); //no exception 
var temp = queryable.Skip(100).Take(10).ToList(); getting exception

private static void ImporterDataMigrateToRmgDb(SourceDBEntities sourceDb, RmgDbContext rmgDb)
{
        int skip = 0;
        int take = 10;

        int count = sourceDb.FormAs.Where(x=> x.FormAStateId == 8).GroupBy(x=> x.ImporterName).Count();
        Console.WriteLine("Total Possible Importer: " + count);            

        for (int i = 0; i < count/take; i++)
        {
            IOrderedQueryable<FormA> queryable = sourceDb.FormAs.Where(x => x.FormAStateId == 8).OrderBy(x => x.ImporterName);

            List<IGrouping<string, FormA>> list;

            try
            {
                list = queryable.Skip(skip).Take(take).GroupBy(x => x.ImporterName).ToList(); 
                //this line is getting timeout exception from the skip value of 100.
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                sourceDb.Dispose();                    
                rmgDb.Dispose();

                sourceDb = new SourceDBEntities();
                rmgDb = new RmgDbContext();

                skip += take;
                continue;
            }

            if (list.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var l in list)
                {
                    List<FormA> formAs = l.ToList();

                    FormA formA = formAs.FirstOrDefault();
                    if (formA == null) continue;

                    Importer importer = formA.ConvertToRmgImporterFromFormA();
                    Console.WriteLine(formA.FormANo + " " + importer.Name);

                    var importers = rmgDb.Importers.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower() == importer.Name.ToLower()).ToList();
                    //bool any = rmgDb.Importers.Any(x => x.Name.ToLower() == formA.ImporterName.ToLower());
                    if (importers.Count() == 1)
                    {
                        foreach (var imp in importers)
                        {
                            Importer entity = rmgDb.Importers.Find(imp.Id);
                            entity.Country = importer.Country;
                            entity.TotalImportedAmountInUsd = importer.TotalImportedAmountInUsd;
                            rmgDb.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rmgDb.Importers.Add(importer);
                    }
                    rmgDb.SaveChanges();

                    Console.WriteLine(importer.Name);
                }
            }
            skip += take;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Importer Data Migration Completed");
}
```

Comment: which line got the exception?

Comment: list = queryable.Skip(skip).Take(take).GroupBy(x => x.ImporterName).ToList();

 this line

Comment: please try this. check whether you get the temp data or not. 
var temp = queryable.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
list =temp.GroupBy(x => x.ImporterName).ToList();

Comment: for this var temp = queryable.Skip(90).Take(10).ToList(); no exception 

but for var temp = queryable.Skip(100).Take(10).ToList(); getting exception

Comment: try to find out the actual SQL which is hitting the SQL server. then run the raw SQL into the server and see what happens.

Comment: I tried this it is giving the expected data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132895/discussion-between-md-sabbir-ahamed-and-foyzul-karim).

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed my problem by modifying following code

```
var queryable =
                sourceDb.FormAs.Where(x => x.FormAStateId == 8)
                    .Select(x => new Adapters.ImporterBindingModel()
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                        Active = true,
                        Created = DateTime.Now,
                        CreatedBy = "System",
                        Modified = DateTime.Now,
                        ModifiedBy = "System",

                        Name = x.ImporterName,
                        Address =  x.ImporterAddress,
                        City = x.City,
                        ZipCode = x.ZipCode,
                        CountryId = x.CountryId
                    })
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

Comment: why does this work? I am also having the same problem. Getting records at the last page always throws a timeout exception. In fact, after the first 10 pages (with 100 records per page), it will throw a timeout exception. Note, I have about 350 million records. Any idea how to fix it?